# WordPress Vue Plugin with single file component - cannot use import

Tags: javascript, wordpress, vue.js

I'm new to WP and Vue.js
I'm trying to create a plugin for WP in Vue that takes data from WP API and print a simple table.

Here's my plugin files:

custom_plugin_name.php

```
<?php

/**
 * Plugin Name: custom_plugin_name
 * Description: WordPress Vue.js plugin
 * Version: 1.0
 */


// Register API Endpoints
[...]


// Register scripts
function func_load_vuescripts() {
    // Register Vue.js and scripts
    wp_register_script('wpvue_vuejs', 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js');
    wp_register_script('my_vuecode', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'vuecode.js', 'wpvue_vuejs', true );
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'func_load_vuescripts');


// Create shortscode function
function func_wp_vue() {

    // Load Vue.js and scripts
    wp_enqueue_script('wpvue_vuejs');
    wp_enqueue_script('my_vuecode');

    return file_get_contents(plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . './App.vue');
}

// Add shortscode
add_shortcode( 'wpvue', 'func_wp_vue' );
```

vuecode.js

```
import App from './App.vue'

var app = new Vue({
    el: '#vuejs-container',
    template: '<App/>',
    components: { App }
})
```

App.vue

```
<template>
    <div id="vuejs-container">
        <h1>My Todo App!</h1>
        <AppTable/>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import AppTable from "./components/Table.vue";

    export default {
        components: {
            AppTable
        }
    };
</script>
```

When I run this code I get two errors on the two import statements (in vuecode.js and App.vue):
Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

I've even try to include vuecode.js script with type="module" attribute but doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import all of your vue components in the `vuecode.js` file. Also, make sure to specify all your components when instancing your vue.js app.

```
import App from './App.vue'
import AppTable from './components/Table.vue';

var app = new Vue({
    el: '#vuejs-container',
    template: '<App/>',
    components: { 
        App,
        AppTable
    }
})
```

Comment: You're right! Thank you! 
Now I have a new problem in console.
"Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec."  
One for each .vue file

Comment: Are you trying to import your vue files directly in javascript ?  Because the vue components must be compiled into JS first